# How do I change the JVM installed by gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I installed gradle 6.6.1 at some point and after running `gradle -v` I get the following output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_265 (Private Build 25.265-b01)
OS:           Linux 5.8.0-40-generic amd64
```

I can also tell that the JDK1.8 is installed (unsurprisingly) in the gradle directory

```
(base) polortiz@myPC:/snap$ sudo find . -name "*jdk*"
./gradle_/32/etc/java-8-openjdk
./gradle_/32/opt/gradle/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar
./gradle_/32/opt/gradle/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar
./gradle_/32/opt/gradle/lib/plugins/bcpg-jdk15on-1.64.jar
./gradle_/32/opt/gradle/lib/plugins/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar
./gradle_/32/opt/gradle/lib/plugins/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar
./gradle_/32/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
./gradle_/32/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
./gradle_/32/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
./gradle_/32/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
./gradle_/32/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_openjdk-8.py
./gradle_/32/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jdk-headless
./gradle_/32/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
./gradle_/32/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
./gradle_/32/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

I want to use JDK15 for all of my projects, not 8.

I already installed JDK15 and my default java file is from there:

```
(base) polortiz@myPC:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
(base) polortiz@myPC:~$ java --version
openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
(base) polortiz@myPC:~$
```

However, gradle keeps trying to build using JDK1.8. How can I get it to update its JDK? I don't want to edit the build.gradle for every project to specify the path to the newer JDK, I want gradle to default to that JVM.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: From my understanding, that solution is project-specific. Aka it requires changing build.gradle. But also, it didn't work for me anyways :(

Comment: As far as I know, Gradle does not "install" any JDK [unless you're using toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:provisioning). The daemon runs using the Java specified by `JAVA_HOME` or, if specified, `org.gradle.java.home`.